# cannot update VS2015 Xamarin.Forms to v2.3.1.114 using Nuget

Tags: xamarin.forms

The lastest stable for Xamarin.Forms is v2.3.1.114 and I've tried to update VS2015 on 3 different machines to this version but they all fail with error "various packages failed to uninstall", or "Xamarin.Android.Support.Vector.Drawable.23.4.0.1 failed to uninstall". Nuget reverts to v1.5.1.6471.

Comment: I tried re-installing VS2015 and with a new Blank Xaml App (Xamarin.Forms.Portable) project, I'm getting "Running an x86 based AVD is 10x faster. We strongly recommend creating a new AVD." and there are build errors though no detail is shown.

Answer (score 1):

One thing we can check whether you’re on the latest Xamarin Stable, as required by Xamarin.Forms 2.3.1. Please go to Tools > Options > Xamarin > Other and install any updates there. When updating Xamarin.Forms, avoid “update all” so that the Xamarin.Android.Support packages aren’t bumped to incompatible versions. If that has already happened, you’ll need to remove all the packages, add Xamarin.Forms again, then add the rest of the packages back in.

You may want to try accelerating the Android emulators with HAXM for faster performance. https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/getting_started/installation/accelerating_android_emulators/

If Hyper-V is enabled, Visual Studio’s Android emulator is another good option.  https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/debug-on-emulator/visual-studio-android-emulator/

Comment: I've reinstalled Xamarin/VS2015 twice to no avail:
1. Tools>Options>Xamarin checks show I have the latest version 
2. Nuget updated Xamarin.Forms to latest stable (2.3.1.114) and left supports untouched (following advice)
3. The IOS project doesn't load when I create a new Blank Xaml App solution. Error : The XamarinIOSPackage package did not load correctly
4. the Droid project opens an incompatible emulator and fails (Running an x86 based AVD is 10x faster. We strongly recommend creating a new AVD). The emulator is different since I messed with the SDK Manager.

Comment: I would love to start again and get to where I was a week ago with new projects successfully loading and running the default android emulator. This is the status of other workstations on my network, but this principle workstation is loading a different emulator that I can't seem to remove and projects fail.